# Pygame: Writing Multiple Lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am working on a scoreboard function for my game in which the player inputs there name and then that is written to a text file as the scores. I have managed write to the file and display it again. But it only writes one name which currently gets overwritten every time a new name is entered. So how would I fix this? I have tried doing:

```
f = open('names.txt')
f.writeline(str(name))
f.close()
```

Here is what I am trying to get:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

So how would I do a different line for each name?
Thank you

I can add in multiple names but here is what happens:
[image]
The text file appears correctly but in pygame it appears incorrectly. I want it to be on separate lines like the text file.

Comment: Are you trying to append information to a file?  Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Maxime Lorant answer is what you want. Suppose you have a list with your names.

```
names = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
f = open("names.txt", "a")
for i in names:
    f.write(i + "\n")
f.close()
```

If names.txt was a blank file, now the content of it should like:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

**EDIT**


Now I see what you are trying to achieve. Please see this link :
http://sivasantosh.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/displaying-text-in-pygame/

Basically, the newline character won't work in pygame - you have to change the coordinates of your text rectangle. I am kinda new to pygame but I managed to do what you want and here's my naive approach (I edited code from the link above):

```
#...
f = open("t.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

basicfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
text = basicfont.render('Hello World!', True, (255, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))
textrect = text.get_rect()
textrect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
textrect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery

screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
for i in lines:
    # each i has a newline character, so by i[:-1] we will get rid of it
    text = basicfont.render(i[:-1], True, (255, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))
    # by changing the y coordinate each i from lines will appear just
    # below the previous i
    textrect.centery += 50
    screen.blit(text, textrect)
#...
```

Here's the result:[image]

Comment: I will try this and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Mind if I show you my current code to see if you could help me fit this in?

Comment: Sure. I think I would handle it:)

Comment: The code: https://gist.github.com/GhostFrag1/8ea8e610e3af9e4aff9e as you can ee if you run this you can input your name then that is saved to a text file. When it is closed the reopened the name will be in the top left.

Comment: check it: https://gist.github.com/macfij/8162008 if you have further questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thank you going to try that out now :)

Comment: Please let me know whether this was useful or not.

Comment: One more question. Is there any way you could help me add in ints to the text. As I wish to add this into a game I am working on and the player has a score. So for example it then looks like NAME   50. As when I tried a test so SCORE = 50 then did str(name) + SCORE + "\n" I got an error about mixing int and str

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44116/discussion-between-macfij-and-ghostfrag1)

Comment: [`pygame.Font.render`](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) in `pygame-ce` since `2.1.4` supports newlines, more info about the fork can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/1112q10/pygame_community_edition_announcement/)

Answer (score 1):

As in many programming language, you can open the file in append mode, to write at the end of the current file. This can be achieve by adding a second parameter in `open` which is the mode:

```
f = open('names.txt', 'a')
f.write(str(name) + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: I can open the text but I am trying to write multiple lines of information without overwriting the current text.

Comment: As I said, the `a` mode doesn't overwrite the content of the file opened. Everything you'll write in your file will be placed after the last line.

Comment: Ok got that but how would I put the latest input under current text?

Comment: Don't understand what you want. Please edit your question with **concrete examples** of what you're trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Just edited the question with an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Still unclear. If you just want to write a new name at the end of the file and get 'Name4' at the last line, the response is just above in my post.

Comment: It says, AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'writeline' if I do f.writeline

Comment: Oh yeah, it's `.write` not, `writeline`... See my updated answer.

Comment: Ahh. Now I see the \n too will try that now

Comment: I have done that but for some reason between each name is a box and it has stayed on the same line :/

Comment: add a line break "\n" at the end. file.write("\n")

also, i'm unclear by what you mean by "score"

Comment: Just added an example of my text. And I have done(str(name) + "\n") but that still happens.